# PHP / How to post a dropdown menu option with a Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a dropdown menu containing a list of articles. I want to be able to select an option from the dropdown and press a submit button to initiate the deletion of the article.

Right now articles are deleted when selecting an option from the dropdown, not great usability.

```
    <form action="delete.php" method="get">
    <select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="id">
       <?php foreach ($articles as $article){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
         <?php echo $article ['article_title']; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
    </form>
```

Comment: That's because you have 'onchange="this.form.submit();' in there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the JavaScript (`onchange`) and add a submit `input`:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="get">
  <select name="id">
   <?php foreach ($articles as $article){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
   <?php echo $article ['article_title']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: A simple solution for a novice. Thank you.